# Haskell Using Source File Problems

Tags: haskell

I recently started using Haskell Platform. I created a source file using Wordpad and named it add. I tried double clicking it so I can open it in ghci but I get

<[1 of 1] Compiling Main                                 (C:\add.hs,interpeted)
C:\add.hs:1:6: parse error on input '\'
Failed modules loaded: none.>

What do I do so I can use my source file?. Should I use another text editor?. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Wordpad is what is known as a *rich text editor* - it uses data embedded in the file to do things like font sizes, typefaces, bolding and italicizing text, and so on.

In general, compilers and interpreters expect *plain text* files - files containing just the characters they are to parse.

Yes, you should use another editor. Notepad would work, or you could download something a bit more full-featured.

Comment: Something like notepad++ would work. [ http://www.notepad-plus-plus.org/ ]